# Cannot change background with event trigger. Trigger on IsMouseOver property not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

Why is the following code not working:

```
<Border Focusable="True" Background="Blue" Height="30" Width="30" >
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

When I hover my mouse over that border it does not turn red. Why?

Comment: Move default `Background` value into `Style` as another `Setter` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx#listing)

Comment: Aaaaaaa that was dumb. Trigger should override background. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @dkozl you ought to add your comment as an answer to get credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set first background of border in style instead of setting it in bordre properties.like this :

```
<Border Focusable="True"  Height="30" Width="30" >
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
           <setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

it should work